# Wicket + Ajax + hasDatepicker

Tags: java, datepicker, wicket, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I have a little problem with Wicket 1.5, Ajax and Datepicker.

I begin with:

```
<td>
  <input class="no_float_short timepicker short" 
                     type="text" wicket:id="timeOfDay"/>
</td>
```

When I focus the input, WiQuery correctly show the timepicker popup.

When I target.add(timeOfDayInput) in wicket, after an event, it lost the timepicker popup because it loses the class "hasDatePicker". I tried to set the classname again with:

```
timeOfDayInput.add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", 
                "no_float_short timepicker short hasDatepicker"));
```

but it doesn't work.

Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could override onConfigure in your datepicker.

```
protected void onConfigure()
{
   super.onConfigure();
   add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", "no_float_short timepicker short"));
}
```

This way every render of the component this classes will be attached to the html tag. No need to set them then in your html.

Answer (score 0):

After `target.add(timeOfDayInput)`

You can can do `target.appendJavaScript("$('#" + timeOfDayInput.getMarkupId() + "').datepicker('show')");`
To make the datepicker show again.